# Access google chrome url bar

Tags: java, c++, google-chrome, keyboard

Is there possible to access the chrome url bar without any chrome plugin.
I want to make a file which check all the time url bar whenever `www.examle.com` is enter in url bar this file show a message like `any message`. How can I do that in java or cpp any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

That is going to be very difficult to do with without a chrome plugin or some sort of external plugin. I've seen something similar done on a strictly Windows application using all Windows API, but if you go that route then you obviously lose any chance at a platform agnostic application. Sorry I could not be of more help. Good luck!